# Cannot properly replace img with its css equivalent

Tags: html, css

I don't want to use `<img>` for things like button icon, error hints etc

Currently, I have this mark-up to render error messages:

```
<p>
    <img src="/path/to/error.jpg" />An error occurred 1
</p>

<p>
    <img src="/path/to/error.jpg" />An error occurred 2
</p>
```

It renders, like (pseudo-view)

```
[img] An error occured 1
[img] An error occured 2
```

It works exactly the way I want, but the problem is `<img>` tag, which I don't want to be used at all.

**So, I've tried** to replace `img` tag  with,

```
<style>
    #error {
        background-image  : url(../images/error.jpg);
        background-repeat : no-repeat;
        width             : 130px;
        height            : 30px;
    }
</style>

<p>
    <div id="#error"></div>An error occured 1
</p>

<p>
    <div id="#error"></div>An error occured 2
</p>
```

But it renders, like

```
[img] 
 An error occured 1
[img] 
 An error occured 2
```

**I've also tried** to play with its `width` and `height`, added `left`, but with no luck.

Again - **the problem** is that,

```
[img] 
 An error occured
```

it renders this way with aforementioned `#error` style.

**The question**,

I want this with `#error` css definiton, without `img` tag to be rendered like this,

```
[img] An error occured
```

What else should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `background-position` property. Here is an example for the same

```
#error {
    background: url(../images/error.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: (width of image);
}
```

and markup would be

```
<div id="#error">An error occured 1</div>
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ysE4w/)